# Is it possible to map an Rc<T> to get an Rc<Subpart-of-T>?

Tags: rust, reference-counting

I have an `Rc<Option<T>>` but need to get an `Rc<T>` from it. Something like:

```
let rc_option: Rc<Option<T>> = Rc::new(Ok(value));
let ok_value: Rc<T> = rc_option.map(|option| option.unwrap());
```

Is this even remotely possible? It seems like something that should make sense, as the `Rc` could just increment the counter it has internally for the new mapped value, but I can't find any docs for it.

Comment: What would you get if the inner `Option<T>` is `None`?

Comment: " It seems like something that should make sense", not at all. Also, if you end having `Option<T>` there is a reason, so why want to remove `Option` ? If you don't need it just don't use `Option`

Comment: Re: option, it's just an example, imagine it try to get a field in a struct that always exists instead.

Comment: @Stargateur: It's possible with C++ `shared_ptr` to get a `shared_ptr` to a field, or element of an array, and share the same "counter".

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't see the rational, this seem very unsafe, basically how do you free the `ptr` if the last `shared_ptr` don't contain the good `ptr` ? This seem just to break the api of `shared_ptr`. Possible != should

Comment: @Stargateur: C++ supports `shared_ptr<void>`. It just requires type-erase when the first `shared_ptr` is created, where it captures a destructor for the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short Answer

No, it's not possible to create a `Rc<T>` from an `Rc<Option<T>>` that leaves the latter still existing. It is possible to create an `Rc<&T>` however, from a `Rc<Option<T>>`, while still leaving the latter variable existing.

### Long Answer

If you're trying to create a new `Rc<T>` that owns the `T` inside the `Rc<Option<T>>`, you will have to consume the original `Rc<Option<T>>`. You also can't have multiple instances of the `Rc<Option<T>>`, because then you're moving the shared value while pointers still exist, which is very unsafe.

But there is a way to do this safely! Using `Rc::try_unwrap`, you can attempt to move the value out, but this will return an error if multiple instances of the original `Rc` exist.
Keep in mind you also have to handle the scenario where `Option<T>` ends up being `None`.

Here's an example of this:

```
let rc_option: Rc<Option<T>> = Rc::new(Some(value));

match Rc::try_unwrap(rc_option) {
    Ok(option) => {
        match option {
            Some(t) => {
                let ok_value: Rc<T> = Rc::new(t);
                // Do something with ok_value
            }
            None => {
                // Do something else here
            }
        }
    }
    Err(rc_option) => {
        // There are multiple owners, do something else here
    }
}
```

If you wanted to preserve the original, you could do this:

```
match &*rc_option {
    Some(ref t) => {
        let ok_ref: Rc<&T> = Rc::new(t);
    }
    None => { /* Do something else, there's no internal value */ }
}
```

---

EDIT: As Chronial mentioned, do note that the `ok_ref` cannot outlive `rc_option` (because it's a reference to `rc_option`), which may not be what you want to happen.

Comment: It should be noted that the new Rc<&T> will have its lifetime bound to the original Rc<T> (i.e. it can't outlive it), which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You're right. I'll update my answer to mention this.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped my understanding.

Comment: `&T` is `Copy`, so there's really no point in stuffing it in a new `Rc` because it can't prolong the lifetime of the original `T`. You might as well just use `t` inside the `match`

Comment: I only put `&T` inside the `Rc`(in this example)  because they were looking to map the value into an `Rc`. I was showing how you can generate an `Rc` that contains the value of the original without consuming it, but also being constricted by lifetime of the original value.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not with Rc.

This is not possible with `Rc` simply because of its memory layout:

```
//  Equivalence:
struct RcBox<T> {
    strong: AtomicUsize,
    weak: AtomicUsize,
    data: T,
};

struct Rc<T> {
    ptr: *const RcBox<T>,
};
```

Therefore, the counters are expected to be right next to `T`, and so you cannot share counters between two distinct elements.

---

#### Alternatives are likely possible.

From a memory-layout point of view, it is perfectly acceptable to create an alternative `FlexRc`:

```
struct Counters {
    strong: AtomicUsize,
    weak: AtomicUsize, // if support for FlexWeak is desired.
    ptr: *mut (),
    drop: fn(*mut ()),
}

struct FlexRc<T> {
    counters: *mut Counters,
    ptr: *const T,
}
```

And this one could in theory allow mapping... however creating a safe interface over it may not be easy.

How do you prevent the user from returning an unrelated lifetime in `map`? Is guaranteeing the lifetime of the return reference exceeds that of `flex` sufficient to be safe?

```
fn fool(flex: FlexRc<Option<i32>>) -> FlexRc<i32> {
    let i = 3;
    flex.map(|_| &i)
}
```

Comment: Hmm yes, if you could enforce returning on a sub part of the value in the Rc would this be safe? Like ensuring it's only a field of the value, if it were a struct? No idea how you would do that though.

Comment: @CallumRogers: It would be safe... though I just realized it'd be leaking :) Counters need to know the original pointer and have a function to run its destructors. I've got no idea how to enforce the lifetime relationship properly, though.

Comment: @CallumRogers: So, added destructor to `Counters`, since it's the actual owner of the data. For lifetime relationship, I think we can constrain the lifetime accepted by the lambda: `FnOnce(&'a T) -> &'a U`... but it's not clear it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As ThatOneDeveloper stated in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54209238/758345), that is not supported by the standard library. You could implement such a feature yourself:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct RcSome<T>(Rc<Option<T>>);

impl<T> RcSome<T> {
    fn from(rc: &Rc<Option<T>>) -> RcSome<T> {
        RcSome(rc.clone())
    }
}

impl<T> Deref for RcSome<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) ->  &T {
        self.0.as_ref().as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Then you can do this

```
let rc_option: Rc<Option<T>> = Rc::new(Some(value));
let ok_value: RcSome<T> = RcSome::from(&rc_option);
```

Note that this will panic if `rc_option` contains `None`. But `ok_value` will now behave like a `Rc<T>` – i.e. you can `clone()` it and do `ok_value.some_method_of_T()`. `ok_value` does also not share a lifetime with `rc_option`, so it can outlive it.